# jquery validation addmethod regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to create custom regex.

I am in that step:

```
    // Custom method to validate username
    $.validator.addMethod("usernamecheck", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Username must contain only letters, ndvdvumbers");
```

This regex disallows to use whitespaces. But I only want to disallow white spaces on beginning and end.

And I also want to be able to use characters like `ł, ś, ş, ń, ą`  those. How should I edit my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._-](?:[A-Za-z0-9._ -]*[A-Za-z0-9._-])?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aH7nB6/1)

To match special characters, u need to add the unicode values into the character class as follows:

```
^[\u0142\u015B\u015f\u0144\u0105A-Za-z0-9._-](?:[\u0142\u015B\u015f\u0144\u0105A-Za-z0-9._ -]*[\u0142\u015B\u015f\u0144\u0105A-Za-z0-9._-])?$
```

[DEMO WITH UNICODE](https://regex101.com/r/aH7nB6/2)

Comment: @TabMan , you are welcome, check the answer to know how to match special characters, I updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start with "Any non white-space character" and end with "Any non white-space character":

```
/^\S.*\S$/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/hY5iP0/1

Comment: btw, maybe, like another option, you can trim the user input.